# alignment of webpage asp.net

Tags: html, css, asp.net

I am creating a webpage which has been divide into two sides. On the left there is an image and on the right there can be various user inputs. I put the image into a table cell with float left and the inputs into a cell and float right.

Everything look like what I expect until I add a grid on the right using

```
<tr>
  <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1">
  </asp:GridView>
</tr>
```

Then the alignment of the contents on the right all move to the bottom of the left hand side. Can anyone can help me on this how to make it stick back to the right?

Here is my mark-up

```
<table id="leftT">
  <tr id ="table_left" >
    <td>
      <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" Height="356px" ImageUrl="~/Image/search.jpg" Width="200px" style="vertical-align:text-top"/>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
<table id ="rightT">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <asp:Label ID="lblUserName" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
    </td>
    <td>
      <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" DataTextField="USERNAME" DataValueField="USERNAME">
            <asp:ListItem></asp:ListItem>
      </asp:DropDownList>
      <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:SOConnectionString %>" ProviderName="<%$ ConnectionStrings:SOConnectionString.ProviderName %>" SelectCommand="SELECT USERNAME FROM USERMASTER WHERE USERSTATUS = 1 AND USERACCESSRIGHTS = 'Non-Administrator'"></asp:SqlDataSource>
    </td>
    <td>
      <asp:Label ID="lblCreateOnM" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
    </td>
    <td>
      <asp:Label ID="lblCreateOn" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <asp:Label ID="lblDate" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
    </td>
    <td><asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" onclick="Button1_Click" Text="Button" />
      <asp:TextBox ID="txtDate" runat="server" Enabled="False"></asp:TextBox>
      <asp:Calendar ID="Calendar1" runat="server" OnSelectionChanged="Calendar1_SelectionChanged"></asp:Calendar></td>
    <td>
      <asp:Label ID="lblUpdateOnM" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
    </td>
    <td>
      <asp:Label ID="lblUpdateOn" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <asp:Label ID="lblTask" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
    </td>
    <td>
      <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList2" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource2" DataTextField="TASKNAME" DataValueField="TASKNAME">
        <asp:ListItem></asp:ListItem>
      </asp:DropDownList>
      <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource2" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:SOConnectionString %>" ProviderName="<%$ ConnectionStrings:SOConnectionString.ProviderName %>" SelectCommand="SELECT DISTINCT TASKNAME FROM TASKMASTER"></asp:SqlDataSource>
    </td>
    <td>
      <asp:Label ID="lblUpdateByM" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
    </td>
    <td>
      <asp:Label ID="lblUpdateBy" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here The mistake you are doing is, you are creating two tables one below the other.Instead take only one table and two  columns and places all the controls in these two columns as shown below

ex-

```
 <table>
       <tr>
          <td id='Left_id'>
             //Put all the left controls here
          </td>
          <td id='Right_id'>
              //Put some controls here if required

             <table>
                 <tr>
                   <td>
                     //some Controls Here 
                   </td>
                 </tr>
             </table>
          </td>
       </tr>

    </table>
```

Comment: assign the with of 2 columns as <td style="width:50%">